# Change selected value event not working for <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code doesn't work when the selected value of drop down changes. Please correct if any error.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
          ("#theSelect").change(function(){
            alert("a");
          });
        });

      </script>

    </head>

  <body>
    <select id="theSelect">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing `$`/`jQuery` => `("#theSelect").change(function(){`

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the `$` before `("#theSelect")`

```
$("#theSelect").change(function(){
```

Comment: Aww you are fast :) +1

Comment: thanx...very very...luv u all...may God bless u all...

Answer (score 2):

`$` is missing, so jQuery won't identify it.

Change as below

```
$("#theSelect").change(function(){
       alert("a");
});
```

Comment: thanx...very very...luv u all...may God bless u all

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select").change(function(){
    alert("a");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <select onchange=categories(this);>
        <option value="option1">Option1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option4</option>
        <option value="option5">Option5</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function categories(el) {
            var category = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(category);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```